# Excel Office Pro 2010 SUMIF

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Hi Im trying to SUMIF(range;"<>#N/A";range) but the cells im selecting to sum are not in a row adjacent, its every 4th cell in the row.

But when i try it gives an argument error each time i try with this for example:

```
=SUMIF(C6,G6,K6,O6,S6,W6,AA6,AE6,AI6,AM6,AQ6,AU6;"<>#N/A")
```

Should i use a different function to achceive this or am i missing a peice of this?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer so will only comment.  I think you need the SUMIFS command for multiple selections, not SUMIF.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i should have explained better sorry. I have an table showing three colums for each month, budget spend and variance, at the end i wish to add all the budget colums in to their own YTD budget, spend and variance colums. As the table has vlookups there are N/A values that need to be ignored (not counted as zero but ignored completely). After you suggestion it now looks like this but is returning 0 instead of an error this time. >=SUMIFS(C6,G6,K6,O6,S6,X6,W6,X6,AA6,AE6,AI6,AM6,AQ6,AU6,"<>#N/A")<

Comment: You aren't defining your range properly. Check the documentation for sumif and for sumifs

Answer (score 0):

I think this formula will do the trick.

```
=SUMIF(C6:G6:K6:O6,"<>#N/A",C6:G6:K6:O6)
```